# Parse number with cortana

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, cortana, windows-10-universal

I have a Cortana XML file and I need to input a number. What should I do to ensure I can convert it to a number?

```
<Command Name="AddMoney">
  <Example> Add 10 dollars </Example>
  <ListenFor> add {amount} {currency} </ListenFor>
  <Feedback> Adding some money </Feedback>
  <Navigate/>
</Command>

<PhraseList Label="currency">
    <item>dollar</item>
    <item>euro</item>
    <item>pound</item>
</PhraseList>

<PhraseList Label="amount">
</PhraseList>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to receive numbers, but it is not perfect.

```
<PhraseTopic Label="amount" Scenario="Commands">
  <Subject>Phone Number</Subject>
</PhraseTopic>
```

Note I'm using **PhraseTopic** instead of **PhraseList**. I don't really know which `Scenario` is the best here, but I found `Commands` to yield better results than having no `Scenario` set. The PhraseTopic tag must be placed after all PhraseList tags for some odd reason...

When trying subjects, the auto complete feature showed a few options where the most promising were `Date/Time`, `Addresses` and `Phone Number`. When trying with multiple subjects I could never have a match, but with "Phone Number" (or just "Number" even if there's no such option) I was able to receive number values somewhat consistently.

The number cames in digits form, so I only need `int.TryParse(myText, out myNumber)` and use it or say something as "invalid number input".

Be aware that any thing can be input here, even with the subject and scenario restrictions... The folowing will work:

```
"Hey Cortana, MyAppName add blah blah blah dollars"
```

And the amount will literally be `"blah blah blah"`